# PySimpleGui can not access list in InputCombo

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am making a simple gui for my python script with PySimpleGui and enterd a problem. Everytime i want to add a new integer to my InputCombo list, I can not access the new integer.

I wrote a basic script to show:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
things=["a","b"]
layout=[[sg.Input(key="-input-",size=(10,1)),sg.Button("add",key="-add-")],
        [sg.InputCombo(things,key="-combo-"),sg.Button("write")],
        [sg.Text("",key="-output-"),sg.Button("Quit")]]
window=sg.Window("Name",layout,size=(200,200))
while True:
    event,values=window.read()
    if event==sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event=="Quit":
        break
    if event=="add":
        things.append(values["-input"])
    if event=="write":
        window["-output-"].update(values["-combo-"])
```

I have a list "things". I can add a new value, if I write something in the inputfield. WIth the Button "add" i add  the value to my list "things". With the InputCombo I can access the vvalues in my list, for example "a" and "b". If I choose "a" or "b" an press "write", the Textfield will update and write "a" or "b". But in the InputCombo I can n ot choose values,  which I have added later.
Does anybody have an idea how I can get things working?

Comment: Button `add` just add new item into list `things`, not into `sg.InputCombo`. You need to update `sg.InputCombo` with option `values=things`. `event=="add"` is wrong, should be `event=="-add-"` because you set key of button `add` as '-add-'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I dont get it. I am relative new to PySImpleGui. I have changed `add` to `-add-`.

Comment: Replied in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call method `update(values=things)` of `sg.InputCombo` to update new values.

Revised code,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

things = ["a","b"]

layout = [
    [sg.Input(key="-input-", size=(10,1)),
     sg.Button("add", key="-add-")],
    [sg.InputCombo(things, key="-combo-"),
     sg.Button("write")],
    [sg.Text("", key="-output-"),
     sg.Button("Quit")],
]
window = sg.Window("Name", layout, size=(200, 200))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == "Quit":
        break
    elif event == "-add-":                          # Correct event to add
        things.append(values["-input-"])
        window['-combo-'].update(values=things)     # Statement to update
    elif event == "write":
        window["-output-"].update(values["-combo-"])

window.close()
```